# Chomsky Normal Form of |a|<|b|

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

Hello Everyone I was hoping I could ask you to check to my work on this CNF, 
These are a pain to me and I want to make sure I'm doing it right the first time

```
The language: 
     L = {w|w accepts |a|<|b|} i.e.abb, bab, b   
    ____________       
    The Grammar:  
    S-> Tb,bT,SS,b  
    T->aTb,bTa,TT,lamda      
    ______________
    The CNF:  
    S-> Tb,bT,SS,b  
    T->aTb,bTa,TT   
    *take out lamda* *I see no unit rules so we can skip a step*(right?)   
    ______________    
    S-> TB,BT,SS,B    
    T->ATB,BTA,TT  
    A->a  
     B->b

    ______________
    S-> C,D,SS,B  
    T->AC,DA,TT  
    A->a  
    B->b  
    C->TB  
    D->BT
```

I think this is correct but I am not confident. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Comment: `{w|w accepts |a|<|b|}` does not make sense. Do you mean $|w|_a < |w|_b$, that is $w$ that have fewer $a$ than $b$?

Answer (score 1):

In your last grammar you included some unitary productions like $S \to C \mid D \mid B$ so it is incorrect. Remember the steps to transform a CFG into CNF are:

1) Eliminate $\epsilon$ productions.

2) [Optional] Eliminate useless productions.

3) Eliminate unitary productions.

4) Adjust the resulting productions to meet CNF requirements.

You didn't have to replace $C \to TB$ in $S \to TB$ because it already meet the CNF requirements.